# Adding resource generators from SettingKey of Seq[Reference] and Reference-scoped settings?

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a `SettingKey[Seq[Reference]]` and I want to add resource generators for every `Reference` in a `Seq` that are dependent on settings scoped to the `Reference` itself, e.g.

```
resourceGenerators in Compile <++= theReferencesKey.map { (refs) =>
  refs.map { ref => (name in ref, somethingElse in ref, resourcesManaged).map {
    (name,somethingElse,resourcesDir) => {
      // The resource generation returning Seq[File]          
    }
  } }
}
```

I know, that this code does not work, because the types are completely wrong. I think, what I would need is

1. A monadic sequence operation: `Seq[Task[T]] => Task[Seq[T]]`
2. A monadic bind operation (`flatMap`) that works with the initialize type...?

I can't find either in the ScalaDoc

Where can I find this kind of information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're working at the `Initialize` level here.  I'm not sure we actually expose `traverse` directly, although we should.   Just a note:  `Initialize` doesn't have a fully general flatMap/bind operation.  It is only applicative, as is Task.  We have a fake flatMap we use, but it's sub-optimal for our purposes.

The second issue you have is that resourceGenerators is a `Seq[Task[Seq[File]]]`, which takes an `Initialize[Task[Seq[File]]` in its `<++=` method

Your nested expression creates an `Initailize[Task[Seq[File]]`.

Your key can give you a `Initialize[Seq[Reference]]`

For any `Reference`, you have a method `Reference => Initialize[Task[Seq[File]]`

So now we play follow the types.

Generically, that's the crazy of

```
def traverse-y(seq: `M[Seq[T]]`,  modifier: T => M[N[Seq[U]]): M[N[Seq[U]]
```

We require `M[_]` and `N[_]` are applicative.

Scala's not so good at abstracting things like `Applicative[M[N[_]]]` out, so we do it old skool: just write it directly

```
 def makeInitialize(refs: Seq[Reference]): Initialize[Seq[Task[Seq[File]]]
    def oneGenerator(ref: Reference): Initialize[Task[Seq[File]] =
      (name,somethingElse,resourcesDir) => {
        // The resource generation returning Seq[File]          
      }

    val allGenerators: Seq[Initialize[Seq[Task[Seq[File]] = theReferencesKey map oneGenerator
    val joinedGenerators: Initialize[Seq[Seq[Task[Seq[File]]]] = allGenerators.join
    val unified: Initialize[Seq[Task[Seq[File]]]] = joinedGenerators mapInit (_.flatten)
    unified
  }
```

And here's the rub:  There is no initialize flatMap, so you'll want to track those Ref's directly.  That's how we handle the situation here: https://github.com/typesafehub/activator/blob/master/project/build.scala#L205-L207

In any case, I didn't get into why initialize has no flatmap, but that's something I can document as well.  Also, a note, the above is considered super-advanced API.  As I said before, I'd love to expose a few convenience functions around this.   unfortunately, the nested Applicatives make life rough when you're at this level.   Throw an `InputTask` in there and you'll really have some fun.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer! I finally got my code to work the way I want to. :)